# How to obtain non-trivial solution of equal ratios

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

How can I obtain a non-trivial solution of the following:

$$\frac{a}{b+c}=\frac{b}{c+a}=\frac{c}{a+b}$$

The answer is $a=b=c=1$.

Comment: Are you sure that this is about the software _Mathematica_?

Comment: Why $a=b=c=\frac{1}{2}$ is better than e.g. $a=b=c=1$ or just $a=b=c=d$ for any complex $d$???

Comment: yes, how to program this in mathematica such that it gives the answer given. Otherwise it is giving trivial solution a = b = c = 0, but i dont know how to program for non-trivial...

Comment: @Artes good catch. i m sorry

Comment: Try e.g. `FindInstance[
 a/(b + c) == b/(c + a) == c/(a + b), {a, b, c}, Rationals, 5]`, there are infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps what you looking for is [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html). It will give the whole solution space of your equations.

```
Reduce[a/(b + c) == b/(a + c) == c/(a + b), {a, b, c}, Reals]
```

[image: reduce]

This should make it clear that `a == b == c == 1` is not ***the*** answer.

At the request of the OP in a comment below, here is a non-trivial solution where the three variables are not equal.

```
ratios = a/(b + c) == b/(a + c) == c/(a + b);
ratios /. {a -> 1, b -> -5, c -> 4}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

The values for `a`, `b`, and `c` come from solution sub-space

```
 a > 0 && b < -a && c == (-a^2 + b^2)/(a - b)
```

which can be read off from the result returned by `Reduce`.

Comment: I'm curious why `a == b == c == 1` is not answer???

Comment: @Artes. Of course it's an answer. "... not ***the*** answer" is an English idiom for "not the only answer". It is a short form of "it's an answer, but not the answer".

Comment: @m_goldberg please suggest other answers

Comment: can anybody graphically present the solution set?

Comment: @xclassmechluv. Please stop asking extensions to your question in comments. Either formulate a new question referring to this one, or edit your question so it includes the extensions. You chances for getting the additional information you seek will be much better.

Answer (score 3):

As there are infinite solutions you must limit the scope of your search. You can find your    desired `a == b == c ==1` with f.e.:

```
 FindInstance[
     a/(b + c) == b/(c + a) == c/(a + b) && 
        0 < a < 10 && 0 < b < 10 && 0 < c < 10, 
           {a, b, c}, Integers, 9]
```

> {{a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1}, {a -> 2, b -> 2, c -> 2}, {a -> 3, b -> 3, 
>   c -> 3}, {a -> 4, b -> 4, c -> 4}, {a -> 5, b -> 5,    c -> 5}, {a ->
>   6, b -> 6, c -> 6}, {a -> 7, b -> 7,    c -> 7}, {a -> 8, b -> 8, c ->
>   8}, {a -> 9, b -> 9, c -> 9}}

```
Solve[a/(b + c) == b/(c + a) == c/(a + b) && 
   0 < a < 10 && 0 < b < 10 && 0 < c < 10, {a, b, c}, Integers]
```

> Same output as above

```
Reduce[a/(b + c) == b/(c + a) == c/(a + b) && 
   0 < a < 10 && 0 < b < 10 && 0 < c < 10, {a, b, c}]
```

> 0 < a < 10 && b == a && c == b

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica can solve this problem completely.
It provides three types of non-trivial solutions.

Here we go

The two defining eqations are

```
eq1 = a/(b + c) == b/(c + a);

eq2 = b/(c + a) == c/(a + b);
```

Solving these, one by one, using `Solve` without specifying the variables to solve for

```
Solve [eq1]
```

> ```
> {{a -> b}, {a -> -b - c}}
> ```

```
Solve [eq2]
```

> ```
> {{a -> -b - c}, {b -> c}}
> ```

Solving both simultaneously, as required, gives

```
sol = Solve[eq1 && eq2]
```

> ```
> {{a -> -b - c}, {a -> -(c/2), b -> -(c/2)}, {a -> c, b -> c}, {b -> -(a/2), 
>   c -> -(a/2)}}
> ```

Check the solutions

```
eq1 /. sol // Simplify
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True}
> ```

```
eq2 /. sol // Simplify
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True}
> ```

```
eq1 && eq2 /. sol // Simplify
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True}
> ```

Now let' s look at the solutions one by one

```
{a, b, c} /. sol[[1]]
```

> ```
> {-b - c, b, c}
> ```

```
{a, b, c} /. sol[[2]]
```

> ```
> {-(c/2), -(c/2), c}
> ```

```
{a, b, c} /. sol[[3]]
```

> ```
> {c, c, c}
> ```

```
{a, b, c} /. sol[[4]]
```

> ```
> {a, -(a/2), -(a/2)}
> ```

We see that the first three solutions are structurally different from each other, the fourth is similar to solution 2.

Best regards, Wolfgang

Comment: @ Öskå: Thanks for the editing. How did you treat the Out-parts (now in a separate Grey field indented a bit more than the command, and a thin read vertical line)?